# Smallest eigenvalue of the sum of positive semidefinite non-commuting Hermitian matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices with distinct eigenvalues $a_n>\ldots>a_1$ and $b_n>\ldots>b_1$ respectively. From Weyl's inequalities it follows that the smallest eigenvalue $s_1$ of their sum, $S=A+B$, must obey
$$
s_1\geq a_1 + b_1 \,.
$$
Assume, in addition, that $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite and that they don't commute, i.e. $[A,B]=AB-BA\neq 0$.
Is it true in this case that last inequality becomes a strict inequality, that is $s_1 > a_1 + b_1$? If so, how can one prove this and if not could you provide an argument or counter-example? Also, if not, what extra restrictions should $A$ and $B$ obey so that the strict inequality holds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can construct a conterexample: Let $A$ and $B$ be noncommuting matrices, and assume all their eigenvalues are larger than some positive number $\epsilon$. Assume that the smallest eigenvalue of $A+B$ is strictly larger than $a_1+b_1$.

However, the new block matrices
$$\widetilde{A}=\begin{pmatrix}\epsilon &\\&A\end{pmatrix}\qquad \text{and}\qquad \widetilde{B}=\begin{pmatrix}\epsilon &\\&B\end{pmatrix}$$
also satisfy your assumptions (noncommuting, positive definite). Their smallest eigenvalues are $\tilde{a}_1=\tilde{b}_1=\epsilon$, and the smallest eigenvalue of $\widetilde{A}+\widetilde{B}$ is $\tilde{s}_1=2\epsilon=\tilde{a}_1+\tilde{b}_1$.

Comment: yes, i thought that too, in order to have the strict inequality i think you must have that the intersection of the two eigenspaces relative to $a_1,b_1$ is just $\{0\}$ otherwise you can find an eigenvector for $S$ with eigenvalue $a_1+b_1$.